# WP_List_Table export data to CSV format

Tags: php, wordpress, export-to-csv

I am using `WP_List_Table` class to make a table at back end which fetches records from `myCustomTable`. Is there any feature/plugin available to export the single & multiple rows to `CSV` format. I have tried so many plugin but they all come up with the whole table export.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

yes you can do. this an an example of my code where i use to get the DB table to excel formate. you just replace the DB connection, table,table fields, and query as required this code may helps you

```
<?php
include '../common/inc.common.php';//db connectivity 

$class=$_REQUEST['class_id'];//get the class id
$line .= "\n";
$filename='../app/class_export_student_hsc.csv';// file name
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");

$sql="SELECT t1 . * ,y.aca_year
FROM (
SELECT  name,fathername,school_name,edu_disctrict,revenue_disctrict,nationality,religion,caste,castetype,gender,dob,dobword,mark1,stat
FROM **myCustomTable**
)t1, academic_years y
WHERE t1.academic_year=y.refid
AND t1.class =$class
";


$studentArray=$Cobj->run_query($sql);
$line = "";
foreach($studentArray as $name => $valuee) {
$comma = "";
    foreach($valuee as $key2 => $value){
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $key2) . '"';
    $comma = ",";
}
    $line .= "\n";
    break;
    }
foreach($studentArray as $name => $valuee) {
$comma = "";
    foreach($valuee as $key2 => $value){
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
    $comma = ",";
    }   
    $line .= "\n";
    }
fputs($fp, $line);
fclose($fp);
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you used WP_LIST_TABLE here

Comment: @VasimVanzara: no, its a simple php code to export a table to csv.